# Using **dict as an argument in Django for create/update_or_create methods - Inconsistent Exceptions

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I've a dict that looks like this:

```
profile_data={'trial_duration': 0, 'tac_agreed': True, 'email': 'blahblah@gmail.com', 'signup_method': 'google', 'social_id': '2343432432', 'social_platform': 'google', 'name': 'blahblah tester'}
```

I want to use the update_or_create method to map this dict to two different model objects. However, there seems to be some inconsistencies in how Django handles this.

I have a model SocialInformation:

```
class SocialInformation(models.Model):

    social_id = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    social_platform = models.CharField(max_length=256, choices=SOCIAL_PLATFORM_CHOICES, default='', blank=True, null=True)
```

When I use the following line, it executes with no exceptions and the values are mapped as expected, even tho most the items in the *profile_data* dict are not fields on the *SocialInformation* model, the mapping just ignores the irrelevant one and takes the relevant.

`social_info, created = SocialInformation.objects.update_or_create(defaults={**profile_data})`

However, when I do the same thing for a different model, Profile:

```
class Profile(models.Model):


    owner = models.OneToOneField('auth.User', primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = EncryptedCharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    trial_duration = models.IntegerField(default=7)
    signup_method = models.CharField(max_length=256, choices=SINGUP_METHOD_CHOICES, default='', 
                                     blank=True)

etc. etc.
```

If I execute the same line:

`profile, created = Profile.objects.update_or_create(owner=user, defaults={**profile_data})`

I get the following error:

`FieldError: Invalid field name(s) for model Profile: 'social_id', 'social_platform'.`

Why does it not ignore the fields that are not on the *Profile* model like it does for the *SocialInformation* query?

Comment: Because you are trying to apply default for the fields that do not exists. `social_id` and `social_platform`. In case of `SocialInformation` it had the supplied values as defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not because the models are different, it's because it is updating an object in one case, and creating an object in another.

In the first example, it is updating an object, so the non-fields [are silently ignored](https://github.com/django/django/blob/530dd193f2a1c791c703f3f961e2296cbb316bf9/django/db/models/query.py#L595).

In the second example it is [trying to create the object](https://github.com/django/django/blob/530dd193f2a1c791c703f3f961e2296cbb316bf9/django/db/models/query.py#L607), which does not allow invalid field names.

As an aside, `SocialInformation.objects.update_or_create(defaults={**profile_data})` looks wrong to me. You aren't filtering to find the `SocialInformation` you want to update. It looks like you might have a single `SocialInformation` in your database and are always updating that one. If you added another `SocialInformation` manually (e.g. through the Django admin), then I would expect that line to start throwing a `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception.